# error when installing polymer designer on local machine

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I have cloned the git for polymer designer on my mac. Following the getting started instructions for Polymer designer works fine until I run bower install

```
-bash: bower: command not found
```

Also `index.html` cannot be loaded by the local httpserver.

I see this is a standard error but several solutions on stack. I need to setup this tool locally to add a custom library.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I resolve this error to get bower install to run?

Answer (score 0):

You nee to install bower: http://bower.io/#install-bower

```
npm install -g bower
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this: bower install --save Polymer/polymer

Comment: `Polymer/polymer` is already a dependency in the bower.json file, no use adding it again.